# moderncv \social commands

Tags: xetex, moderncv

I would like to use moderncv `\social` commands without using moderncv as a document class. I tried using: `\usepackage{moderncv}` but then xelatex complains with: ! LaTeX Error: File `moderncv.sty' not found.

I would like to use these icons you can find in this footer: ftp://ftp.ctan.org/pub/tex/macros/latex/contrib/moderncv/examples/template-es.pdf

I'm using the MacTeX-2014 Distribution on my Mac.

Comment: By standard these from the `marvosym` package.  See http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14/15925 .  If you are running xelatex or lualatex they are from the `fontawesome` package.

Comment: @AndrewSwann : yet, the linkedin, twitter and github symbols are not from [`marvosym`](http://mirror.ibcp.fr/pub/CTAN/fonts/marvosym/doc/fonts/marvosym/marvodoc.pdf), but designed using `tikz` in `moderncv`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are able to work with Xe- or LuaLaTeX, you may load the `fontawesome`-package which loads all the symbols used in the new style of `moderncv`:

```
% arara: lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontawesome}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\faPhone{}
\faPhoneSign{}
\faMobilePhone{}
\faTablet{}
\faPrint{}
\faEnvelope{}
\faEnvelopeAlt{}
\faGlobe\\
\faTwitter{}
\faTwitterSign{}
\faFacebook{}
\faFacebookSign{}
\faLinkedin{}
\faLinkedinSign{}
\faGooglePlus{}
\faGooglePlusSign
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

### *Preamble*

1° this solution might not work with Xelatex, try to replace 
`\renewcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}` by `\renewcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontspec{MarVoSym}\char#1}}`.

2° A class is *definitly not a package*

---

### *Solution*

Those symols are defined in the `moderncviconsmarvosym.sty` file.
Some of those symbols come from a font, some where designed using `tikz`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\marvosymbol}[1]{{\fontfamily{mvs}\fontencoding{U}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\selectfont\char#1}}
\definecolor{color2}{rgb}{0.55,0.55,0.55}% Chose your color here.

\newcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\newcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {\marvosymbol{72}~}
\newcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {\marvosymbol{84}~}
\newcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {\marvosymbol{117}~}
\newcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {\marvosymbol{66}~}
\newcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {{\Large\marvosymbol{205}}~}
\newcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.165em}{%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.08em, y=0.08em, xscale=0.25, yscale=-0.25, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
      \protect\begin{scope}[cm={{0.60,0.0,0.0,0.60,(346.39,123.07)}}]
        \protect\path[fill=color2]
          (381,202) -- (434,202) .. controls (439,202) and (442,205) ..
          (442,210) -- (442,264) .. controls (442,268) and (439,272) ..
          (434,272) -- (381,272) .. controls (376,272) and (372,268) ..
          (372,264) -- (372,210) .. controls (372,205) and (376,202) ..
          (381,202) -- cycle;
        \protect\begin{scope}[xscale=0.98, yscale=1.02, fill=white]
          \protect\path[fill=white]
            (403,253) -- (403,224) -- (394,224) -- (394,253) --
            cycle(398,211) .. controls (397,211) and (395,212) ..
            (395,213) .. controls (394,213) and (393,215) ..
            (393,216) .. controls (393,217) and (394,218) ..
            (395,219) .. controls (395,220) and (397,220) ..
            (398,220) .. controls (400,220) and (401,220) ..
            (402,219) .. controls (402,218) and (403,217) ..
            (403,216) .. controls (403,215) and (402,213) ..
            (402,213) .. controls (401,212) and (400,211) ..
            (398,211) -- cycle;
          \protect\path[fill=white]
            (410,253) -- (419,253) --
            (419,236) .. controls (419,236) and (419,235) ..
            (419,235) .. controls (419,235) and (419,234) ..
            (419,234) .. controls (419,233) and (420,232) ..
            (421,232) .. controls (422,231) and (423,231) ..
            (424,231) .. controls (425,231) and (427,231) ..
            (427,232) .. controls (428,234) and (428,235) ..
            (428,237) -- (428,253) -- (437,253) --
            (437,236) .. controls (437,232) and (436,228) ..
            (434,226) .. controls (433,224) and (430,223) ..
            (427,223) .. controls (425,223) and (423,224) ..
            (421,225) .. controls (420,226) and (419,227) ..
            (418,228) -- (418,228) -- (417,224) --
            (410,224) .. controls (410,225) and (410,227) ..
            (410,228) .. controls (410,230) and (410,231) ..
            (410,233) -- cycle;
        \protect\end{scope}%
      \protect\end{scope}%
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}
\newcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {%
  \protect\raisebox{0em}{%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.08em, y=0.08em, xscale=0.005, yscale=-0.005, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
      \protect\path[fill=color2]
        (2000, 192) .. controls (1926, 225) and (1847, 247) ..
        (1764, 257) .. controls (1849, 206) and (1914, 126) ..
        (1945,  30) .. controls (1865,  77) and (1778, 111) ..
        (1684, 130) .. controls (1609,  50) and (1503,   0) ..
        (1385,   0) .. controls (1158,   0) and ( 974, 184) ..
        ( 974, 410) .. controls ( 974, 442) and ( 978, 474) ..
        ( 985, 504) .. controls ( 644, 487) and ( 342, 323) ..
        ( 139,  75) .. controls ( 104, 136) and (  84, 206) ..
        (  84, 281) .. controls (  84, 424) and ( 156, 549) ..
        ( 266, 623) .. controls ( 199, 621) and ( 136, 602) ..
        (  80, 572) .. controls (  80, 573) and (  80, 575) ..
        (  80, 577) .. controls (  80, 776) and ( 222, 941) ..
        ( 409, 979) .. controls ( 375, 988) and ( 339, 993) ..
        ( 301, 993) .. controls ( 275, 993) and ( 249, 991) ..
        ( 224, 986) .. controls ( 276,1149) and ( 428,1268) ..
        ( 607,1271) .. controls ( 467,1381) and ( 290,1447) ..
        (  98,1447) .. controls (  65,1447) and (  32,1445) ..
        (   0,1441) .. controls ( 182,1557) and ( 397,1625) ..
        ( 629,1625) .. controls (1384,1625) and (1796,1000) ..
        (1796, 458) .. controls (1796, 440) and (1796, 422) ..
        (1795, 405) .. controls (1875, 347) and (1945, 275) ..
        (2000, 192);
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}
\newcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {%
  \protect\raisebox{-0.15em}{%
    \protect\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.08em, y=0.08em, xscale=0.25, yscale=-0.25, inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt]
      \protect\begin{scope}[shift={(507,387)}]
        \protect\path[fill=color2]
          (117, 60) .. controls (117, 71) and (108, 81) ..
          ( 96, 81) .. controls ( 85, 81) and ( 75, 71) ..
          ( 75, 60) .. controls ( 75, 48) and ( 85, 39) ..
          ( 96, 39) .. controls (108, 39) and (117, 48) ..
          (117, 60) -- cycle;
        \protect\path[cm={{0.88,0.0,0.0,0.88,(11.10,6.89)}}, fill=white]
          (117, 60) .. controls (117, 71) and (108, 81) ..
          ( 96, 81) .. controls ( 85, 81) and ( 75, 71) ..
          ( 75, 60) .. controls ( 75, 48) and ( 85, 39) ..
          ( 96, 39) .. controls (108, 39) and (117, 48) ..
          (117, 60) -- cycle;
        \protect\path[fill=color2, nonzero rule]
          (103, 45) .. controls (103, 45) and (101, 46) ..
          (101, 47) -- (100, 47) --
          ( 99, 47) .. controls ( 99, 47) and ( 98, 47) ..
          ( 97, 47) .. controls ( 94, 47) and ( 93, 47) ..
          ( 92, 47) -- ( 92, 47) --
          ( 91, 47) .. controls ( 90, 46) and ( 88, 45) ..
          ( 88, 45) .. controls ( 88, 45) and ( 88, 45) ..
          ( 87, 45) .. controls ( 87, 45) and ( 87, 45) ..
          ( 87, 45) .. controls ( 86, 46) and ( 86, 48) ..
          ( 86, 49) -- ( 87, 50) --
          ( 86, 51) .. controls ( 85, 51) and ( 85, 52) ..
          ( 85, 53) .. controls ( 85, 54) and ( 85, 57) ..
          ( 85, 58) .. controls ( 85, 58) and ( 85, 58) ..
          ( 82, 59) .. controls ( 79, 59) and ( 77, 59) ..
          ( 77, 59) .. controls ( 77, 59) and ( 77, 59) ..
          ( 78, 59) .. controls ( 80, 59) and ( 83, 59) ..
          ( 85, 59) .. controls ( 85, 59) and ( 85, 59) ..
          ( 85, 59) .. controls ( 86, 59) and ( 86, 59) ..
          ( 86, 59) .. controls ( 86, 59) and ( 85, 59) ..
          ( 84, 59) .. controls ( 82, 60) and ( 80, 60) ..
          ( 79, 60) .. controls ( 78, 61) and ( 77, 61) ..
          ( 77, 61) .. controls ( 77, 61) and ( 78, 61) ..
          ( 79, 61) .. controls ( 81, 60) and ( 83, 60) ..
          ( 85, 60) .. controls ( 86, 60) and ( 86, 60) ..
          ( 86, 60) .. controls ( 86, 60) and ( 87, 61) ..
          ( 88, 62) .. controls ( 89, 63) and ( 90, 63) ..
          ( 92, 63) .. controls ( 92, 63) and ( 93, 64) ..
          ( 93, 64) .. controls ( 93, 64) and ( 93, 64) ..
          ( 93, 64) .. controls ( 92, 64) and ( 92, 65) ..
          ( 92, 65) .. controls ( 92, 66) and ( 90, 66) ..
          ( 89, 66) .. controls ( 88, 66) and ( 88, 66) ..
          ( 87, 65) .. controls ( 87, 64) and ( 86, 63) ..
          ( 86, 63) .. controls ( 85, 63) and ( 84, 63) ..
          ( 84, 63) .. controls ( 84, 63) and ( 84, 63) ..
          ( 84, 63) .. controls ( 85, 64) and ( 86, 65) ..
          ( 86, 66) .. controls ( 87, 67) and ( 87, 68) ..
          ( 88, 68) .. controls ( 89, 68) and ( 89, 68) ..
          ( 90, 68) -- ( 92, 68) -- ( 92, 70) -- ( 92, 72) --
          ( 91, 72) .. controls ( 91, 72) and ( 91, 73) ..
          ( 91, 73) .. controls ( 90, 73) and ( 90, 73) ..
          ( 91, 73) .. controls ( 92, 73) and ( 92, 73) ..
          ( 92, 73) .. controls ( 93, 73) and ( 93, 73) ..
          ( 93, 70) .. controls ( 93, 67) and ( 93, 67) ..
          ( 94, 66) -- ( 94, 66) --
          ( 94, 69) .. controls ( 94, 71) and ( 94, 73) ..
          ( 94, 73) .. controls ( 94, 73) and ( 94, 73) ..
          ( 93, 74) .. controls ( 93, 74) and ( 93, 74) ..
          ( 93, 74) .. controls ( 93, 74) and ( 93, 74) ..
          ( 94, 74) .. controls ( 94, 74) and ( 95, 74) ..
          ( 96, 73) .. controls ( 96, 72) and ( 96, 71) ..
          ( 96, 68) -- ( 96, 66) -- ( 96, 66) --
          ( 96, 69) .. controls ( 96, 72) and ( 96, 72) ..
          ( 97, 73) .. controls ( 97, 74) and ( 99, 74) ..
          ( 99, 74) .. controls ( 99, 74) and ( 99, 74) ..
          ( 99, 73) .. controls ( 99, 73) and ( 98, 73) ..
          ( 98, 72) .. controls ( 98, 72) and ( 98, 66) ..
          ( 98, 66) .. controls ( 98, 66) and ( 99, 66) ..
          ( 99, 66) .. controls ( 99, 67) and ( 99, 67) ..
          ( 99, 69) .. controls ( 99, 71) and ( 99, 72) ..
          ( 99, 72) .. controls ( 99, 73) and (100, 73) ..
          (100, 73) .. controls (101, 73) and (101, 73) ..
          (101, 73) .. controls (102, 73) and (102, 73) ..
          (102, 73) .. controls (101, 72) and (101, 72) ..
          (101, 69) .. controls (101, 66) and (101, 65) ..
          (100, 65) .. controls (100, 64) and (100, 64) ..
          (100, 64) -- ( 99, 64) --
          (100, 63) .. controls (101, 63) and (102, 63) ..
          (103, 63) .. controls (104, 62) and (106, 61) ..
          (106, 60) -- (106, 60) --
          (107, 60) .. controls (109, 60) and (113, 60) ..
          (115, 61) .. controls (115, 61) and (115, 61) ..
          (115, 61) .. controls (115, 60) and (111, 60) ..
          (108, 59) .. controls (107, 59) and (107, 59) ..
          (107, 59) .. controls (107, 59) and (107, 59) ..
          (107, 59) -- (107, 59) --
          (108, 59) .. controls (110, 59) and (112, 59) ..
          (114, 59) .. controls (115, 59) and (115, 59) ..
          (115, 59) .. controls (115, 59) and (112, 59) ..
          (109, 59) .. controls (108, 58) and (107, 58) ..
          (107, 58) .. controls (107, 58) and (107, 58) ..
          (107, 58) .. controls (107, 57) and (107, 56) ..
          (107, 55) .. controls (107, 53) and (107, 53) ..
          (107, 53) .. controls (107, 52) and (106, 51) ..
          (106, 50) -- (105, 50) --
          (105, 48) .. controls (105, 47) and (105, 46) ..
          (105, 46) -- (105, 45) --
          (104, 45) .. controls (104, 45) and (104, 45) ..
          (103, 45) -- cycle;
      \protect\end{scope}%
    \protect\end{tikzpicture}}%
  ~}

\begin{document}
\mobilephonesymbol
\fixedphonesymbol
\faxphonesymbol
\emailsymbol
\homepagesymbol
\linkedinsocialsymbol
\twittersocialsymbol
\githubsocialsymbol
\end{document}
```

yields : 
[image: The symbols for mail, twitter, etc.]

By playing with the fonts, you can obtain a different outcome.

Comment: You're welcome. I made a quick answer that could get enhanced on several levels to have a uniform colour, to remove that `\addresssymbol` useless symbol, to show how to use different fonts, etc. I just copy / pasted and adapted a bit the moderncv relevant file.