# Want to add the different icons in Friggeri Resume like email, phone, mobile, skype etc

Tags: fonts, xetex, luatex, cv, friggeri-cv

Want to add the different icons in Friggeri Resume like email, phone, mobile, skype etc.

```
\documentclass[]{myfriggeri-cv}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}

\begin{document}
\header{friggeri}{friggeri}
   {social network analyst}


% In the aside, each new line forces a line break
\begin{aside}
\section{about}
 Street
 City
 Country
 ~
\href{mailto:friggeri@gmail.com}{friggeri@gmail.com}
\href{http://friggeri.net}{http://friggeri.net}
\href{http://facebook.com/friggeri}{fb://friggeri}
\section{languages}
 english
 Germans  \& French
\section{programming}
 {\color{red} $\varheartsuit$} \LaTeX
 (MATLAB)
  C, C++
 %CSS3 \& HTML5
\end{aside}

\section{objective}

\section{interests}

complex networks, social networks, community detection, community structure,
overlapping communities, information diffusion, viral marketing, social
inference, recommendation, data mining

\section{education}

\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{since 2009}
{Ph.D. {\normalfont candidate in Computer Science}}
{DNET/INRIA, LIP/Ã‰NS de Lyon}
{\emph{A Quantified Theory of Social Cohesion.}}
\entry
{2007-2008}
{Master in  Scientific Computing}
{DNET/INRIA, LIP/Ã‰NS de Lyon}
{Majoring in complex networks\\
Specialization in data mining}
\entry
{2003â€“2006}
{Classes PrÃ©paratoires aux Grandes Ã‰coles}
{LycÃ©e FÃ©nelon, LycÃ©e Louis le Grand, Paris}
{Preparation for national competitive entrance exams to leading French ``grandes   Ã©coles'', specializing in mathematics and physics.}
\entry
{2003}
{French BaccalaurÃ©at S. with honors}
{LycÃ©e Louis le Grand, Paris}
{Specialization in mathematics and physics}
\end{entrylist}

\section{experience}

\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{02â€“07 2009}
{LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
{Research Internship.}
{\emph{Visualization of complex networks.}}
\entry
{06â€“08 2008}
{ISCPIF/CNRS, Paris}
{Research Internship.}
{\emph{Diffusion in the Blogosphere. Happy Flu.}}
\entry
{06â€“08 2007}
{LIP6/CNRS, Paris}
{Research Internship.}
{\emph{Kernels in real world networks.}}
\entry
{07â€“08 2005}
{\href{http://www.kelkoo.com}{Kelkoo.com}}
{Summer job.}
{\emph{Creation of a keyword generator for Google Adwords.}}
\entry
{07â€“08 2004}
{\href{http://www.monsieurprix.com}{MonsieurPrix.com}}
{Summer job.}
{\emph{Development of an e-commerce product indexation spider.}}
\end{entrylist}

\section{applications}

\begin{entrylist}
\entry
{2012}
{Who did I forget ?}
{\href{http://whodidiforget.com}{whodidiforget.com}}
{Guest list recommendation for Facebook events based on friends already attending the event.}
\entry
{2011}
{Fellows}
{\href{http://fellows-exp.com}{fellows-exp.com}}
{Automatic community detection among Facebook Friends in order to validate the     \emph{cohesion} measure, creation of friend lists.}
\entry
{2008}
{Happy Flu}
{\href{http://happyflu.com}{happyflu.com}}
{Experiment aimed to measure viral spreading of content across the blogosphere.}
\end{entrylist}

\section{publications}
\section{hobbies}
\section{reference}
\section{information}

\printbibsection{article}{article in peer-reviewed journal}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={international peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, notkeyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\begin{refsection}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[sorting=chronological, type=inproceedings, title={local peer-reviewed conferences/proceedings}, keyword={france}, heading=subbibliography]
\end{refsection}
\printbibsection{misc}{other publications}
\printbibsection{report}{research reports}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Your question is not easy to understand: where do you want to add them? What did you tried ? Beside, your code is not minimal at all. However, you should have a look at [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188359/34551).

Comment: @Clément used these icons in \section{about}

Comment: Rather than copy / pasting the default file of the [friggeri resume](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv), I think you should:  1° Give a link to the template you used, 2° Say if you tried the [http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/fontawesome](Fontawesome) package / font?

Comment: I am trying this code also but still it's not working for Skype icon. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121891/friggeri-resume-very-different-rendering-in-different-readers

Comment: Regarding the Skype Icon, you should have a look at [that answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/141196/34551).